# php executing curl not working

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am trying to run a shell command from php to update a dns ip address but it doesn't work and I don't see why it's not working.

```
$ip =  $_POST['ipAddress'];
$exc =shell_exec("curl -L https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/dns?username=testtt@yahoo.com&password=sfddeaeZZ.&hostname=example.sytes.net&ip=$ip&#8221");
```

when I type directly in the console

```
curl -L https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/dns?username=testtt@yahoo.com&password=sfddeaeZZ.&hostname=example.sytes.net&ip=$ip&#8221"
```

it works but with php it doesn't.

Comment: why not use php curl function?

Comment: i have tried but maybe something was not right.

Comment: Make sure PHP has CURL installed. It's a lot easier than trying to use the CLI

Comment: i think that the script does run, but you dont see the output because you are not forwarding it into the right place.  do this `echo  exec("$command",$output,$return_code); echo $output; echo $return_code;`

Comment: [5]   Done                    ip=$ip -here is something wrong, it doesn't take the IP that is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to execute CURL using php's built in functions:

```
<?php 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/dns?username=testtt@yahoo.com&password=sfddeaeZZ.&hostname=example.sytes.net&ip=$ip&#8221");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

as @Machavity commented make sure curl is installed and enabled.

Comment: it's not working for me, maybe has to do with this in the url ? &ip=$ip   because $ip =  $_POST['ipAddress'];

Comment: If you think that is the case simply try with $ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx . Replace the xxx's with your ip address and check

Comment: aah sorry it works, I just forgot something from the url, thank you